# Can you give me half? (No digits)

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source

The task is to provide code that evaluates to 0.5 numerically, i.e. the output must be recognized by your chosen language as a numeric value (Number, float, double, etc), not as a string. The catch, the characters 0 through to 9 cannot be used.

PLEASE NOTE: This IS NOT a golfing challenge, this is a popularity contest, so creative answers are encouraged. The more obscure and convoluted answers are also encouraged.

One example that fits the brief would be the following:

`((++[[]][[~~""]]<<++[[]][[~~""]]))**((--[[]][[~~""]]))` which works out to 0.5 in JavaScript.

A bounty of 150 will be awarded as an added incentive for the most voted creative answer. Good luck!

Any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Wow, 34 answers in the very same day! And yet with 5 downvotes and only barely enough upvotes to break even. That really says something... if only I knew what! (How controversial popularity contests with no objective criterion are?)

Comment: TBH, @AviFS it surprises me that people forget there are more different categories of challenges than just code golf... I want my fellow golfers to embrace their inner goofball and provide more esoteric and convoluted answers based on their language of choice... And there was an objective, output half without numeric digits... ;)

Comment: It's not that the challenge is not code golf, it's that it's the blandest, most generic kind of popularity contest -- a trivial task where we're asked to be creative with "obscure and convoluted answers". At that point all pop cons might as be merged into one challenge that says "write whatever you want, upvote every answer".

Comment: I'll be coming up with a proper golf challenge shortly... I promise @xnor...

Comment: @xnor It's clear that this isn't what we want for the majority of the site . But is "write whatever you want, upvote every answer" really such a bad thing every now & then?

Comment: This wouldn't be fun as code-golf either.  It's just a boring, and IMO off-topic, question.

Comment: @WheatWizard I haven't seen a challenge get 40 answers the day-of in a long time. I wonder if we're not missing pretty clear signs that this is the way to ramp up engagement. It's certainly more inviting, and the barrier to entry is less rigid. Perhaps we're elitists in our ivory towers to be demanding objectivity & strictly defined winners everywhere we go.

Comment: @AviFS 40 answers in a day is not a good sign.  In fact it is a *very* bad sign.

Comment: Code trolling also caused a massive spike of activity back in 2014 @AviFS, that doesn't mean they were quality questions. More answers doesn't not equal a quality question. Pop-cons have been a controversial topic for years, but it is possible to run a pop-con that isn't just "Do this but creatively"

Comment: What exactly classes as "code trolling"...?

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio [tag:code-trolling]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 177 bytes

```
Never gonna give you up,
Never gonna let you down,
Never gonna run around and desert you.
Never gonna make you cry,
Never gonna say goodbye,
Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BDsMwCATvfQUPqPqU/IHWqzSJCxEJqXi9Yzk91AckxKyGnZFzlDLggNGoIkzjdIBCnXy93/5Bxt7uSb/SE3MhNnVJxHUSNljLPrrYh5fL/LLoBRtH3TQ9Az3Yaz@qryc089t/3lJO)

Explanation thanks to caird coinheringaahing.

```
Never gonna give you up,                Helper Link; never called
Never gonna let you down,               Helper Link; never called
Never gonna run around and desert you.  Helper Link; never called
Never gonna make you cry,               Helper Link; never called
Never gonna say goodbye,                Helper Link; never called
Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you.    Main Link
Never gonna tell a lie and hurt yo      Random stuff that doesn't matter
                                  u     Undefined so everything before it gets trashed
                                   .    0.5
```

... yeah. Not that exciting when you see how it works.

Comment: Props for the Rick-roll... Well played...

Comment: Got to love undefined behaviour and chain breaking...

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing ngl I don't know how this works

Comment: @hyper-neutrino The `u` at the end of `you` is undefined, which breaks the chain and ignores everything before it. Therefore, the only code that's executed is `.`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing ... wow, lol :D (also, there are ASCII characters with no defined meaning? o.O)

Comment: Only `h`, `q` and `u` are currently undefined of the ASCII characters, makes them very useful for this kind of "hidden" functionality :)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing well that explains why the `h` in `hurt` stopped `d` from causing issues with trying to `divmod` by 0... I thought I was losing my mind and forgetting how monadic 2,2 chaining worked lmao.

Comment: Lyxal is going to be jealous of you....

Comment: People complain all the time about golfing languages being unfair, but have they tried making something more popular that this?

Answer (score 28):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/)

```perl
Once upon a midnight dreary, while "I pondered", !weak and weary;
Over many a quaint and curious volume of for@gotten, @lore;
While I nodded, nearly napping, until /|there came a tapping|/;
As if someone ? ${!gently} = "rapping" ^ "rapOing at": my $chamber, $door;
"Tis some visitor", I-muttered, "tapping at my chamber door";
print unpack f, ${!this} and nothing x more
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVA9T8MwEN3zK16tjkadWIgQZezUBYkNycSXxKp9Fxy7JaL97cFJuz3p3fu6gaJ/nucjN4Q8CMMgOMuu6xNsJBMnjUvvPEEdUHhLkazS2FzInGDY4rIc1dXxTBHB8FQcfrJxnFa2ydFJHnEWnwNBWrQS952kRKyx9xKprj7XgANYrCWrwcXST2AzDI47jczJeeyuqS/paEwxMkh39rqrq/cRrsUogYQJb9j@bTri5KcbXqHi/VDha8XHgmGSekGYsG16E74pamytSKwr9eHG1QlnN7oksWw9PIVc@salmnrEFodF/5BjEau6GuKyO/NgmhNavRRJvRtv6ytYCi7KX4Syep7/AQ)

Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December;
And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.

#### Explanation / Spoiler:

Perl has a feature called 'barewords', which allows alphanumeric sequences to automatically be parsed as strings. This means that something like

```perl
foo bar baz
```

Will parse as valid Perl, but give a runtime error. However, if we can avoid Perl evaluating it, we can avoid the runtime error. The following program will run without any error:

```perl
foo bar baz while 0
```

Now let's have a look line by line:

```perl
Once upon a midnight dreary, while "I pondered", !weak and weary;
```

`"I pondered", !weak and weary` evaluates essentially to `("I pondered", false)` which is falsy so the stuff on the left hand side of the while loop does not get evaluated.

```perl
Over many a quaint and curious volume of for@gotten, @lore;
```

This is a `for` loop over the lists `@gotten` and `@lore`, which are empty, so the left hand side doesn't get evaluated.

```perl
While I nodded, nearly napping, until /|there came a tapping|/;
```

This is an `until` loop, where `/|there came a tapping|/` is a regex matching against `$_`. Even though `$_` is empty, the leading `|` matches against the empty string so the match becomes truthy so we don't evaluate the left hand side.

```perl
As if someone ? ${!gently} = "rapping" ^ "rapOing at": my $chamber, $door;
```

`if` is a keyword here. `someone` is a bareword which is truthy, so we evaluate `${!gently} = "rapping" ^ "rapOing at"`, which sets `${''}` to the string `"\0\0\0?\0\0\0 at"`. `my $chamber, $door` parses as a function call which is never evaluated, so there's no error.

```perl
"Tis some visitor", I-muttered, "tapping at my chamber door";
```

`I` and `muttered` are both barewords.

```perl
print unpack f, ${!this} and nothing x more
```

This parses as `(print unpack f, ${!this}) and nothing x more`. `${!this}` is `${''}`, which is our string from earlier. `unpack f` is a function that unpacks a single 32 bit float from a packed 4 byte representation. The first 4 bytes of `${''}` are `"\0\0\0?"`, which happens to be a valid representation of `0.5`. The rest of the string is ignored.

Since `(print unpack f, ${!this})` is truthy, the right hand side of the `and` is evaluated. `x` is the string repeat operator, and `nothing` and `more` are both barewords, so there's no error generated.

Comment: Wait, how does Perl 5 know how to parse the code from the rest of Edgar Allen Poe's prose?

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio as a hint, have a look at the Perl keywords that are highlighted in blue. There's multiple kinds of syntax abuse here.

Comment: I see those, but I'm not familiar with Perl's ability to abuse syntax. Any chance you can explain. This is something I've never heard of before, so I'm hoping to understand this more.

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio I have edited in an explanation.

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant...

Answer (score 26):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 5 bytes

```perl6
π/τ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X5xYqfD/fIP@@Zb//wE)

The constant Pi divided by Tau is, of course, `1/2`. An alternative without the pesky unicode is to spell it out like `pi/tau`.

Answer (score 23):

## Python 3, 117 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcgxDsIwDAXQq2SzP4J2YGODi1hBaSESsSOTDl24ekBl7Pb06tqepufeq2dtzK9Y7ikGvbgtmvi9FBbJpZo3ESaPmqwQhj8Ys3mQkDX84jGxAqMezRPTjXDacCUAvPFDOOwA9P4F)

```python
(lambda n:round(sum(__import__('random').random()for _ in range(n))/n,ord('B')-ord('A')))(ord('~')*ord('~')*ord('~'))
```

This takes the average of a bunch of random numbers in the range 0-1 then rounds it. There is a *very* small chance this does not evaluate to 0.5

Comment: Love it. It's rare to see non-deterministic solutions on challenges like this.

Answer (score 22):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 122 bytes

```
H   H  AAAAA  L      FFFFF
H   H  A   A  L      F
HHHHH  AAAAA  L      FFFFF
H   H  A   A  L      F
H   H  A   A  LLLLL  ½
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=H%20%20%20H%20%20AAAAA%20%20L%20%20%20%20%20%20FFFFF%0AH%20%20%20H%20%20A%20%20%20A%20%20L%20%20%20%20%20%20F%0AHHHHH%20%20AAAAA%20%20L%20%20%20%20%20%20FFFFF%0AH%20%20%20H%20%20A%20%20%20A%20%20L%20%20%20%20%20%20F%0AH%20%20%20H%20%20A%20%20%20A%20%20LLLLL%20%20%C2%BD&inputs=&header=&footer=)

You asked for half, so I've given you half in more ways than 1 (/2).

This relies on the fact that most things here are NOPS and that getting the length of a number works.

The real work comes when we get to the `L`s in the bottom row: the first `L` is passed, 0, which has length 1. The next 4 `L`s all return 1 because the length of 1 is 1. The `½` then divides that 1 by 2.

Answer (score 18):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), "HALF OF ONE"

Yes, Jelly can output half of one with just `.` but did you know there is a secret verbose mode with a certain lexicon of ***reversed English***?

```
ENO FO FLAH
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Vz1/BDYh8HD3@/wcA)**

#### How?

OK, so I lied.

```
ENO FO FLAH - Link: no arguments            (implicit 0)
E           - (implicit [0]) all equal?            -> 1
 N          - negate                               -> -1
  O         - ordinal (a no-op with numeric input) -> -1
    F       - flatten                              -> [-1]
     O      - ordinal (vectorises; again a no-op)  -> [-1]
       F    - flatten                              -> [-1]
        L   - length                               -> 1
         A  - absoulte value                       -> 1
          H - halve                                -> 0.5
```

Comment: Wow, I really like this one!

Answer (score 16):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/v/38A)

I know it isn't golf, but why be creative when the tools are provided for you?

`.` is a decimal literal in Jelly. When the values before the `.` is omitted, it defaults to `0` and after it defaults to `5`. Therefore `.` is just `0.5`

Comment: I feel like you just put a full stop to this challenge.

Comment: Polyglot with Vyxal: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=.&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 15):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/)

A.k.a "the worm".

```
=⊸÷⟜≠⌾‿⌾
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=PeKKuMO34p+c4omg4oy+4oC/4oy+)

Produces a 2-element list consisting of two built-ins (`⌾`), then divides the rank (1) by the length (2).

Various superfluous parentheses and no-ops can be added for style:

`(=÷≠)(⌾‿⌾)`
`=(⊸)(÷⟜≠)(⌾‿⌾)`
`⊣(=)(⊸)(÷⟜≠)(⌾‿⌾)`
`(=)(⊸)(÷)(⟜)(≠)(⌾‿⌾)`

Or how about the chicken and the owl:

`(≡÷≠)⊢⟨˙⋄˙⟩`
`(≡÷≠)⊢⟨⌾,⌾⟩`

Comment: +1 for the cute smiley face of the worm 

Answer (score 15):

## C (GCC, MIPS)

```c
// A very mysterious function
float mystery()
{
    // A very mysterious string
    char whaaaaaa['?'] = "?";
    // A very mysterious cast
    return *(float *)whaaaaaa;
}
```

> If you want to test it on a non-based x86 or ARM CPU, try `htonl('?')`.

##### Explanation

> The reason I choose MIPS is because I wanted it to be big endian.
>  The convenient thing about 0.5f is it is represented as `0x3f000000`. `0x3f` is `?` in ASCII.
>  The string will be stored as `3f 00 00 00 ...` in memory, and dereferencing it on a big endian machine will conveniently result in `0x3f000000`.

Comment: Isn't MIPS bi-endian?  This should work on any big-endian machine, right?

Comment: yes, the important thing is big endian. MIPS32 is usually big endian.

Answer (score 14):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 75 bytes

```
ElementData["Hydrogen","AtomicNumber"]/ElementData["Helium","AtomicNumber"]
```

The atomic numbers of hydrogen and helium are exactly 1 and 2, respectively. Atomic masses aren't exact (except for carbon-12's, by defintion, when expressed in daltons), but atomic numbers are, since they're simply the number of protons in the atoms of the element.

[Not sure how to get this working in TIO, or if solutions requring a server connection are allowed in popularity contests.]

Comment: Loving this, the BSc from my university years took notice of this one!

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio I find calling the Wolfram server from within a Mathematica notebook has become the easiest way to get basic data on elements and compounds.  But in that case, unless I need something very specific, I'll prepend an `=` so I can use Wolfram Alpha's natural language input, to avoid the heavy syntax.  E.g.:  `=molecular weight glucose` instead of `ChemicalData["DPlusGlucose", "MolarMass"]` (or, even worse, `MoleculeValue[Entity["Chemical", "DPlusGlucose"], {"MolarMass"}]`).

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 420 bytes

```python
from math import*
H=lambda n:int(n,int(sqrt(ord('Ā'))))
o=ord
print(round(sin(H('d')*pi/(H('d')-H('a')))*cos(H('d')*pi/(o('G')-ord('A')))-sin(H('b')*pi/(o('G')-ord('A')))*cos(-(H('f')-H('a'))*pi/(H('d')-H('a'))))/(round((sin(pi/(o('h')-o('a')))*(pi/(o('h')-o('a'))))+(sin((H('f')-H('a'))*pi/H('e'))*(H('f')-H('a'))*pi/H('e'))+(sin(sqrt(o('@'))*pi/((o('h')-ord('a'))))**(H('d')-H('a')))+(sin(sqrt(o('Q'))*pi/H('e'))))))#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVC7DsIgFN37FU0ceGjTwc2kiU529ROo2JREHlIc3Pw4/wu5lKo17R3gwnncA@bhOq223rdWy1wy1@VCGm0dzerqymTDWa52QjmsNrD2N@uwthyj1xORUJmuwjEzFlCr74rjXihcY8QRoUaUqS3CxkBBz7r/hTVGxwBHzwMQiqRvlgjRoQBK@/WdG0XKlChGSl4deI1Z5i7JOtJn/EN7gXYZGqTDJ2G0H3N9RsAbhiGU/qedak9TY6iV928)

Directly from my math book. Solving it by bare hands was a big pain. But writing this answer from mobile was fun. oh plus got a nice byte count.

$$
\frac{\sin \frac{13\pi}{3}\cos 
\frac{13\pi}{6}-\sin \frac{11\pi}{6}\cos \left(-\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)}{
\sin^2\frac{7\pi}{3}+\sin^2\frac{5\pi}{14}+\sin^2\frac{8\pi}{7}+\sin^2\frac{9\pi}{4}}=0.5
$$

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript, 67 bytes

Abuses the fact that `undefined` is a valid identifier in JS.

```js
undefined=>(undefined=>undefined/(undefined+undefined))(!undefined)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66h8b80LyU1LTMvNcXWTgOJDWfqI0S14SxNTQ1FBOe/poam5n8A)

Comment: What's the mechanism behind this?

Comment: @JamesHyde My (possibly incorrect or incomplete) understanding: It may be more readable as `f = a=>((b=>b/(b+b))(!a))`. When you call a function in JS with fewer arguments than declared, the rest are set to `undefined`, so when we call `f()`, `a` is set to `undefined`, so we have `((b=>b/(b+b))(!undefined))`. `!undefined` is `true` in JS (because `undefined` is falsey(?)), so we have `(true/(true+true))`. doing arithmetic to `true` makes it behave as `1`, so we have `(1/(1+1)) == (1/2) == 0.5`

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
Ænɓ,ÆṛUÆrḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//w4ZuyZMsw4bhuZtVw4Zy4bii//8)

I already made an answer that fits with Jelly's ability to be short. How about an answer about Jelly's ability to have stupidly convoluted builtins?

We construct the polynomial \$4x^2 - 4x + 1\$, then solve it as equal to \$0\$, giving \$x = \frac 1 2\$

### How it works

```
Ænɓ,ÆṛUÆrḢ - Main link. Takes no arguments
Æn         - Next prime after zero; 2
  ɓ        - New dyadic chain f(2,2):
   ,       - Pair; [2,2]
    Æṛ     - Construct the polynomial with the roots 2, 2: [4,-4,1]
      U    - Reverse; [1,-4,4]
       Ær  - Get the roots of this polynomial; [0.5, 0.5]
         Ḣ - Get the first element
```

Why use 1 byte when lot byte do trick?

Comment: Loving it, nice and convoluted!

Answer (score 10):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/)

Line number trickery.

```ruby
p __LINE__ -
  __LINE__ **-
  __LINE__ *
  __LINE__ .
  to_f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhPt7H0881Pl5Bl0sBwdHSQuUic/SAnJL8@LT//wE)

#### Explanation

`__LINE__` is a global constant which stores the current line number. As such, the program can be rewritten into one line as: `p 1-2**-3*4.to_f`, which just so happens to evaluate to `0.5`. The `.to_f` is needed to cast the result to a float (otherwise `(1/2)` is printed).

Comment: Bravo! Love this train of thought!

Answer (score 8):

## [Dyalog APL](https://dyalog.com)

```
÷∊⊆⊂∪⊃⊢⊣⊥⍨⍲⍀∨\⍱⌿∧/↑↓⍎⍕⍋⍒⍸⍴⍪,⍉⊖⌽⌹|⌈⌊*¨⍟⍤○⍥!×+~-≢⍬⍝
```

EDIT: I've updated the picture & text, but not the link nor the explanation.

[Try it online!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=DczPCgFhFIfha7H1JzfkUiRRX2eO81OIWUkN00yTDSkspMydvFdi9k9P@8QcT/gCa/AlXuBnvEQ1uqM5uhFfrJ5g1Zi0Ie3QGu3RCm3RCz1QM0QZfiA@xHtKGOH9X7ec0IW8s2WvzQezEVmBruj4Bw&f=AwA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=%E2%8E%95)

Uses as many unique primitives as I had the patience to cram in. Andvmany thanks to Adám for giving me a bunch more to cram in! It looks cooler with a proper APL font:

[image: Code]

(That is, as many primitives as I could use in a linear chain of execution without parentheses. I'm sure you can use every single one if you allow parentheses, as that opens up the dyadic functions.)

#### Explanation

```
÷        Inverse            ->  1/2
↑        Mix                ->  2
↓        Split              ->  2
⊃        First              ->  2
∪        Unique             ->  2
⊂        Enclose            ->  2
⊣        Same (left)        ->  2
⊢        Same (right)       ->  2
∨\       Scan with GCD      ->  2
∧/       Reduce with LCM    ->  2
⍸        Where              ->  [1,2]
⍴        Shape              ->  [1,1]
⍪        Table               ->  3
,        Ravel              ->  3
⍉        Transpose          ->  3
⊖        Horizontal flip    ->  3
⌽        Vertical flip      ->  3
|        Absolute value     ->  3
⌈        Ceiling            ->  3
⌊        Floor              ->  3
*        Exponent           ->  3.14159
¨        Map                ->  1.14472
⍟        Natural logarithm  ->  1.14472
⍤        Atop               ->  3.14159
○        Pi times           ->  3.14159
⍥        Over               ->  1
!        Factorial          ->  1
×        Direction          ->  1
+⍨       Add to itself      ->  2
~        NOT                ->  1
-        Negate             ->  0
∊        Enlist             ->  0
≢        Length             ->  0
⍬        Empty list         ->  []
```

Comment: `⍬` can be `#∩⍬`

Comment: `⊃` can be `⊃⍣=`

Comment: So many symbols ⍤

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg)

```perl6
say ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVLh0N7//wE)

Doesn't need explanation, does it?

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
cTyT
```

[Try it here!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=cTyT&debug=0)

Divides ten by twice ten.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

```c
float f(){float x=' ';x/='@';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8tJz@xRCFNQ7MawqqwVVdQt67Qt1V3ULeu/Z@ZV6KQm5iZp6HJVc2lAAQFRUChNA0l1bSYPCUdkEZNa67a//@S03IS04v/65YDAA)

Because \$x\$ is a `float` the characters `' '` (\$32\$) and `'@'` (\$64\$) get converted to floating point numbers. Then the GCC trick of returning the last calculation is used to return \$\frac{1}{2}\$.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended)

```apl
#÷⍥≢⍬⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L/y4e2Pepc@6lz0qHcNEIEE/yuAQQEA)

Divides the length of a reference to the root namespace (1) by the length of `[[],[]]` (2).

Comment: I'm sure you were going for creative, rather than golfy, but [here it is golfed!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230158/87594)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL)

```apl
⎕←⌈∘○⍢÷*≢~≢⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz//1Hf1EdtEx71dDzqmPFoevej3kWHt2s96lxUB8SPetf8/w8A)

`⍬` the empty list; `[]`

`≢` its length; `0`

`~` logical NOT; `1`

`*` *e* to the power of that; `2.71828…`

…`⍢÷` while inverted; `0.36787…`

`∘○` multiply by π; `1.15572…`

`⌈` round up; `2`

Then we "un-invert"; `0.5`

Answer (score 5):

## Desmos, 686 bytes

```
f\left(x\right)=\frac{\frac{\left(\csc x\right)\left(\csc x\right)-\left(\cot x\right)\left(\cot x\right)}{\left(\sin x\right)\left(\sin x\right)}-\frac{\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)-\left(\sin x\right)\left(\sin x\right)}{\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)-\left(\cos x\right)\left(\cos x\right)}}{\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\left(\cos x\right)\left(\cos x\right)-\cos\left(x+x\right)+\left(\left(\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)\right)\left(\cos x\right)\right)\left(\left(\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)\right)\left(\cos x\right)\right)\right)\right)+\left(\csc x\right)\left(\csc x\right)-\left(\cot x\right)\left(\cot x\right)}
```

Or rendered properly:

\$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\frac{\left(\csc x\right)\left(\csc x\right)-\left(\cot x\right)\left(\cot x\right)}{\left(\sin x\right)\left(\sin x\right)}-\frac{\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)-\left(\sin x\right)\left(\sin x\right)}{\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)-\left(\cos x\right)\left(\cos x\right)}}{\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\left(\cos x\right)\left(\cos x\right)-\cos\left(x+x\right)+\left(\left(\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)\right)\left(\cos x\right)\right)\left(\left(\left(\sec x\right)\left(\sec x\right)-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan x\right)\right)\left(\cos x\right)\right)\right)\right)+\left(\csc x\right)\left(\csc x\right)-\left(\cot x\right)\left(\cot x\right)}\$

[Try it online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5jlojbydjf) Defines a function f that will return 0.5 no matter what you put into it, pretty much. It will barf on multiples of π/2 though. Sorry if Desmos lags a bit.

Comment: Tried \$f(0)\$ and got undefined...

Comment: @AidenChow Most inputs. tan barfs on 0, sec barfs on π/4, etc.

Answer (score 5):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <s>14</s> 7 bytes

```
e/(e+e)
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jsi7cvuzau)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://python.org), 71 bytes

```python
from http import HTTPStatus
print(HTTPStatus.OK/HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST) # 200/400
```

Comment: `# 200/400` number spotted /s

Comment: Another creative solution! Excellent!!

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 35/12 bytes

```
Limit[(-I*I-Cos[x])/(x*x),x->I/∞]
```

The starting point for this is the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

To eliminate the numbers, I then replaced 0 with ⅈ/∞, 1 with –ⅈ^2, and x^2 with x*x:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow i/\infty}\frac{-i^2-\cos(x)}{x*x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Or, less fancy:

```
-I*I/Floor@E
```

$$\frac{-i*i}{\lfloor e \rfloor} = \frac{1}{\lfloor \approx 2.718 \rfloor}  =\frac{1}{2}$$

[Wasn't sure if the etiquette is to combine this with my previous answer or post separately but, following Caird's example, I did the latter.]

Comment: I think this is my favorite. Just straight math.

Answer (score 4):

## JSFuck, 2443 bytes

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]])+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])()((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]+[+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([+[]]+![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])
```

Quite big

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`

```
½ .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeal5mcn5KqUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiYP3/0F4Fvf//AQ)

---

Or, slightly more interesting: since Factor has a *ton* of constants and helper words named `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. in private vocabularies, I thought it would be fun to see how far down the alphabet I had to go before arriving at a solution. Turns out not very far. I struck gold with the word `a` from the `math.finance.private` vocabulary which is defined as `: a ( n -- a ) 1 + 2 swap / ; inline` Or, in math terms: \$a(n)=\frac{2}{n+1}\$. Then, I just had to find a value of \$3\$ which turns out to be defined in `checksums.md5.private` as `CONSTANT: d 3 inline`. So:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.finance.private checksums.md5.private`

```
d a .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7GqlUFCUWlJSWVCUmVfC5Rbk72ulkJtYkqGXlpmXmJecqgeUKEssSVWwtVNIVLCGqkjOSE3OLi7NLdbLTTFFVpKiYP0/BahQ7/9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
_"_-:@-:_"_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/45Xida0cdK2A9H9NrtTkjHyFNAV19f8A)

- In J, `-:`, as a dyadic verb, means "do the two things match?" and, as a monadic verb, means "half".
- `_` is the literal symbol for infinity.  Adding `"_` turns it into a verb of infinite rank that always returns the value infinity.  This is required syntactically for the right version of `_"_`, and we add it to the left one for symmetry.
- Now, for any argument, the verb checks if `_` is equal to `_`, and always returns 1.  And half of 1 is 0.5.

Comment: Though of course `%#_ _` would do.

Comment: Sure, but not as pretty :)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/)

```apl
(+-÷)⍨⍣(×≡#⍬)≢⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@Gtu7h7ZqPelc86l2scXj6o86Fyo9612g@6lwEpEBK/iuAQQEA)

`⍬` the empty list; `[]`

`≢` its length; 0

`(`…`)` compute:

`#⍬` a literal; `[reference-to-root-namespace,[]]`

`≡` the depth (nestedness) of that; `-1` (maximum depth is 1, but negative value indicates raggedness)

…`⍣` apply the following tacit function that many times (i.e. find an argument to the following function such that the result is 0 (from the length of the empty list above)

`(`…`)⍨` apply this function with its sole argument as both left and right argument:

`+-÷` the sum minus the ratio

Effectively solves \$x+x-x÷x=0\$ or \$2x-1=0\$ which gives \$x=1÷2=0.5\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 23 bytes

```
<<'<::+/u':':'u/+::<'<<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/GRt3Gykpbv1TdCghL9bWtrIAiNv//AwA)

A reversible one just for fun...

```
<<                       # Shift stack left twice
  '<                     # Push "<" on the stack
    ::                   # Duplicate top of stack twice
      +/                 # Add then divide to get 0.5
        u                # Print as a number
                         # The rest of the code winds up being ignored...  The code just
                         # has to be valid and not generate output.
         ':':'u          # Push "::u" onto the stack
               /+::      # Divide, add, then duplicate top of stack twice
                   <     # Shift stack left
                    '<   # Push "<" on the stack
                      <  # Shift stack left (to an empty stack)
```

And another one that's a mirror image around a central point.

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 21 bytes

```
<<'<::+/'upu'\+::>'>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/GRt3GykpbX720oFQ9RtvKyk7dzu7/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [QBasic (QB64)](http://www.qb64.net/)

```
X = Y = Z
PRINT ATN(X) / ATN(X / Y)
```

> All variables in QBasic are initialized to 0. The first line is `X = (Y = Z)`, where the first `=` is assignment but the second `=` is comparison. Truthy is -1 in QBasic, so now `X` is -1. QB64 allows division by 0, returning floating point infinity (or in this case, negative infinity); \$\arctan(-1) = -\frac \pi 4\$, and \$\arctan(-\infty) = -\frac \pi 2\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 23 bytes

```
\frac{\{\}}{\{\}+\{\}}
```

(newline is required)

Looks crazy, but it really isn't once you figure out that `\{\}` is just `1`.

The actual crazy part is that it doesn't render properly on Desmos, though it still outputs `0.5`.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rkacsrmj1k)

Comment: Using forward slash: `¶\{\}/(\{\}+\{\})` (`¶` is newline)

Comment: @fireflame241 Yes, I know that works, but I wanted to have more brackets in the code to make it look more crazy :P.

Comment: Oh it's a pop-con. Forgot to read the question, oh well.

Answer (score 3):

## [RAMDISP, 19 bytes](https://github.com/Oderjunkie/RAMDISP)

```
[P[[[[]]][/[[]]];]]
```

RAMDISP is my own programming language, but i made it before this challenge, so i think it's allowed. [i also had to fix a bug i left in it, which i only found after trying to do this challenge]

explanation:

```
[P - pipes through the following array
  [
    [[[]]] - the value 2.
    [/ - divide
      [[]] - the value 1.
    ] - by the incoming number.
    ; - print the result
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 57 bytes

```
Ｉ⁻Ｌα⊘Ｌ







https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyOqGRjVtls
```

[Try it online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)[!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPGne/37Pm3MZHXTOANBcUZJSUFBRb6euXl5frVeaXlpQmpeol5@fqlyeWJGfYl9k6VvoXugdlhZXkFP//DwA)

Comment: Interesting, though as I said, this isn't code golf, so whether you golf it down isn't the point... :)

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio Sorry, I'm so used to code golf...

Comment: No worries, I'm trying to come up with a doozy of a gold challenge over the next week or so. Watch this space.

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio [Is this better?](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPGne/37Pm3MZHXTOANBcUZJSUFBRb6euXl5frVeaXlpQmpeol5@fqlyeWJGfYl9k6VvoXugdlhZXkFP//DwA "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Comment: I just "tried it online!" You got me... Really? XD

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 25 bytes

```python
print(len("l")/len("pr"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyc1T0MpR0lTH8woKFLS1Pz/HwA)

Short, sweet, and with only 11 distinct bytes too.

Comment: Taking advantage of the fact that `int()` returns `0`, you can get 9 distinct bytes: `print(~int()/~(~int()//~int()))`

Comment: You can also get 18 bytes total, but it's not very interesting imo: `print(-True/~True)`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
тT*;тT*·<ŸтT*/ΩΔ;t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YlOIljWIOLTd5ugOEEP/3MpzU6xL/v8HAA)

Choose a random float in \$[0.5, 2)\$, and iterate \$x\mapsto \sqrt{x \over 2}\$ until convergence.

In theory the iteration converges to \$0.5\$ for all positive real numbers, but there might be floating point issues leading to results close to \$0.5\$.

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
XΔNÌoz-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/4twUv8M9@VW6//8DAA)

$$
1-\sum^\infty_{k=2}{1 \over 2^k} = 1-{1 \over 2} = {1 \over 2}
$$

```python
X        # start at 1
 Δ       # until the result doesn't change:
  NÌ     #   iteration index N + 2
    o    #   2 ** (N+2)
     z   #   1 / 2**(N+2)
      -  #   subtract this from the current value
```

Comment: Estimating the sum with the first 100 terms would be enough with the floating point precision: [`тL>ozO`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YpOPXX6V////AA)

Comment: True, most languages tend to hit underflow by that number of iterations...

Answer (score 2):

### [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v#v)

```
≈:) :) :) :) :( :( :( )≈)?/;
```

```
≈    Duplicate top of stack (by default stack is [0])
then the :) and :( do nothing, because : executes only the next characted if the top two elements of the stack are not equal, so it skips over the parentheses.

) Increment top of stack -> stack is now [0, 1]
≈ Duplicate top of stack -> stack is now [0, 1, 1]
) Increment top of stack -> stack is now [0, 1, 2]
? Reverse stack -> stack is now [0, 2, 1]
/ Set top of stack to top of stack / second element of stack -> stack is now [0, 1, 0.5]
; Print top of stack
```

[run online](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#f1dc7554bcaf36d13390f3bcf491fb5d01b5e4280070117c31ebcdf2d532bb21)

Comment: Not sure why, but looking at this code makes me smile.

Answer (score 2):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), 2 bytes

```
½
```

Evaluates to, and prints, 0.5. Not necessarily terribly imaginative, but probably one of the best solutions to this problem in Barrel.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 57 bytes

```r
function(`+`=function(x)as.double(as.roman(x)))+'I'/+'II'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfkZiTZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jQTvBFs6p0Ews1kvJL03KSdUAsorycxNBgpqa2uqe6vpAwlMdrF9D8z8A)

As odd as it may sound, R has a partial support for Roman numerals.

So, in this code we:

- abuse the plus sign by turning it into a function accepting Roman numerals strings and returning the numeric value
- we *aesthetically* compute `+I / +II` (we actually calculate `1 / 2` because the abused plus sign act as a roman-to-double parser)
- then we return the result

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

Not very creative but ehh

```python
ord('!')/ord('B')
```

edit: as pointed out by EasyasPi (thanks), doesn't work for python 2

Comment: Python 2 would do integer division here.

Comment: Python 0.66667?

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 82 bytes

```
print divide length? next system/locale/days to-float length? system/locale/months
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcrBCYAwDADAVbKAdAR38Cs@iom2kCbSBLHTx5/gva8TxkK4bnH1Kg5Y74oETHJ6mUHocbBhTi2x7pkpYR4GrtPBmv2L/9NUvFjECw)

Divides the number of days in a week minus one to the number of months. The current Red built doesn't need `to-float`.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 82 bytes

```r
function()round(mean(runif(sqrt(exp(exp(pi)))) - rnorm(sqrt(exp(exp(pi))))),pi/pi)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYlBCsAgDAS/4nEDLX1BHyPWQA5GTRX6@1R67sDAwJjz6Tw1DakKsjr1QslRYVOFcXcbyE/7bEKLsAfTauXv0dbkWOkpDjCI/AU)

Generates the mean of (\$\sqrt{e ^ {e ^ \pi}}\$ random uniform numbers in the range (0, 1) minus \$\sqrt{e ^ {e ^ \pi}}\$ random numbers from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1) and rounds it to 1 decimal place.

Comment: characters 0-9 cannot be used. thats the whole point of the challenge

Comment: @EliteDaMyth oops fixed now

Answer (score 1):

## [ZX Spectrum Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum), 8 bytes

`PRINT SGN PI/INT EXP SGN PI`

This is actually a well-known compression technique for numeric constants. Plain `PRINT 0.5` would require 10 bytes (1 byte for the `PRINT` keyword, 3 bytes for the ASCII string `0.5`, 6 bytes for the float constant)

Comment: Which would be great if we were voting on bytes. This is a code popularity contest, not a code golf challenge.

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio Yes, I know. However, I consider my answer not too bad - in particular, because I independently "discovered" the `SGN PI` expression decades ago, when most programs I saw used `PI/PI`. And it is somewhat elegant as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal)

```
\/C⌐\\C/-
```

##### Explanation:

```
\/C          . gets the codepoint of / 
   ⌐         . 1 - x
    \\C      . gets the codepoint of \
       /     . division (to get -0.5)
        -    . subtract from implicit 0
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C%2FC%E2%8C%90%5C%5CC%2F-&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 30 bytes

```cs
Console.Write('$'/(float)'H');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P/fOT@vOD8nVS@8KLMkVUNdRV1fIy0nP7FEU91DXdP6/38A)

Division of Ascii Codes: '$' = 36, 'H'(alf) = 72

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://python.org), 203 bytes

```python
((True+True)*(True+True+True)**(True+True+True+True)*(True+True+True+True+True)/(True+True+True+True)-(True+True)**(True+True+True)*(True+True+True+True+True)**(True+True))/((True+True)*(True+True)+True)
```

Heh.

Comment: This is invalid as it's a code snippet, not a full program or function

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

```
len('check')/len('check-mate')
# Output: 0.5
```

Comment: NICE!!! Definitely creative. The only one so far to use string manipulation to arrive at the result.

Comment: This is invalid as it's a code snippet, not a full program or function

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
->{($.**=$.).to_f/($.<<$.)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165aQ0VPS8tWRU9TryQ/Pk0fyLWxAfJq/xcopEXH/gcA)

Using the variable `$.` which is initially set to zero, and the interesting property `0⁰==1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 14 bytes

```
d=True;d/(d+d)
```

`True` is basically just `1` in Python, so this is basically just

```
1/(1+1)
```

which obviously evaluates to `0.5`.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your program should output the value, so you should include `print(..)` in your answer

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
~[] / ~~(Math[`SQRT${-~-~[]}`] * Math[`SQRT${-~-~[]}`]) * ~[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvG/LjpWQV@hrk7DN7EkIzohODAoRKVat04XKF6bEKugpYBVXBMoAWT91/wPAA)

The `~~` just before the Math.SQRT2 multiplication is needed because Math.SQRT2 * Math.SQRT2 = 2.0000000000000004.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
÷⌊*≡⍬
```

Not very creative, but golfy! [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9hcGwtZHlhbG9nLWNsYXNzaWP//@KOleKGkMO34oyKKuKJoeKNrP//)

```
÷       Inverse              ->   1/2
⌊       Floor                ->   2
*       Exponent [1]         ->   2.71828
≡       Depth                ->   1
⍬       Empty list           ->   []

[1]: Default base is e, so e^1
```

Comment: It sure is. Thanks @Sisyphus!

Comment: Inverse of log natural to int... I'd say that's pretty creative. Clever, at the very least!

Comment: Or that isnt it, is it? Your solution uses e. Muh bad. Make way, noob stumbling through. XD

Comment: @NateT Thanks! I was actually outgolfed though by Adám, although it's less interesting: `÷≢⍬⍬`. But it means this is neither as golfy, nor as creative, as it could be. This post can't really decide what it wants to be!

Comment: Haha, no worries! Any attention (read validation) is good attention : )

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript

```js
t=true;
console.log((t) / ((t) ^ (t + t) ^ (t)) ** (t));
```

JavaScript works well, here is a simple numerically deficient example getting you the half or it.

Answer (score 0):

## JAVA

As a simple java project. I haven't looked at the others, so it is entirely possible (and likely) that this is the umpteenth answer to contain this solution. This code, placed inside `src/Run.java` of a fresh project, will return o.5.

The actual algorithm is only 2 (sorry, two XD) lines; The rest is just getting it to print. I know you asked for whimsical, but I was impressed with the simplicity of this, so I used it, for better or worse....

This algorithm takes advantage of the fact that any number, when divided by (itself plus itself) will give one half.

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = Math.random();
        double y = x/(x+x);
        System.out.println(y); 
       
    }
```

}

Btw, Im not sure how to do the giant text in md, so I just used a title hash. Ill be back to fix once I figure it out.

EDIT: Although I guess using java for this two line solution is a bit whimsical! LOL

Comment: This is invalid, the code throws a syntax error; If that is fixed Math.random can output 0, throwing an error.

Comment: @emanresu Didnt realize it needed to be fail proof. I was going on the impression that this was more of a "battle of the concepts" type of thing. I wrote this in about 45 seconds just as a way to have fun and blow off steam. didn't realize we were giving points for "most robust." I'll fix it though. Which IDE threw the syntax error. I believe I compiled in STS 4.7? I won't use Intellij products. anything else and I'll pull it up. What is the error?

Comment: The `{` after `public class Run` is unmatched, and Math.random can return 0, meaning that you get `(0+0)/0`.

Comment: @emanresu The { was a copy paste error, and as far as the divide by zero error, I believe that is why I put it as a double.. When run, x goes 12 digits past the decimal point (0.000000000001 precision). Yes, if _all 12_ of those digits end up zeroes, then it will error out, so I added the if block just in case. Just for you.

Comment: That uses digits.

Comment: @emanresuA Good point. So I guess we'll just have to hope that lightning doesn't strike twice (more like three or four times)...

Comment: You still have to have it completely deterministic. You could use something like `'a'.length()` or similar. Please test this, as I don't know Java very well.

Comment: There's no need to give credit to me. Also, submissions to challenges that require constant output have to be deterministic.